# Windows 10, compiling tests from Git Bash will not work "bash: junit-4.12.jar: command not found"

Tags: java, junit, git-bash

Currently doing my first year of studies, and up until now I've been using BlueJ for unit testing my code, which has worked nicely. But now I need to have abstract test classes and interfaces so I need to be able to run the tests from Git Bash. I have downloaded junit-4.12 and hamcrest-core-1.3 and put them in my working directory where the test classes I want to compile are. But I get these two errors when doing it (copied directly from Bash):

```
$ javac -cp .;junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar LinkedListTest.java
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
bash: junit-4.12.jar: command not found
bash: hamcrest-core-1.3.jar: command not found
```

I have Windows 10 and in my enviorment variables I have only edited my path and inserted where my jdk is, nothing else but that and I have been able to compile my regular classes this way, but my test classes will not work!

I have asked recently for help from my recent LABClass where TA:s help us out, but they have been unable to come with any help.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated since I need to do my assignments but I am unable to see if my solutions are viable since I can't test them!

Answer (score 2):

The bash interprets `;` as a command separator. To use it in the classpath this character needs to be escaped:

```
javac -cp .\;junit-4.12.jar\;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar LinkedListTest.java
```

Note: Unix traditionally uses `:` as a path separator character but I guess you are calling the Windows version of javac here.

Comment: Thank you so much my problem is solved! Is there a way I could make it more streamlined so that I dont have to type in the directory every time I want to compile a testclass? I am suspecting it has something to to with enviorment variables, but every tutorial I've read asks me to put it into the JAVA_HOME directory, which is not present in my enviorments. Any thoughs regarding this?

Comment: This is a new question, please post it separately. But maybe https://superuser.com/ is an even better place to ask.